# I've updated jekyll and it doesn't generate posts anymore

Tags: ruby, jekyll

After installing latest beta my posts don't generate. Are there any changes that might broke it? It looks like it just ignores the posts I created after the update even though I always copypaste YAML part of the post from previous one Here's my config file

```
markdown: redcarpet
baseurl: ""
exclude: ["README.md"]
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "_site/posts/page:num/"
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the front-matter from a post?

Comment: @SethWarburton  ---
layout: post *new line*
title: "02.02.2015" *new line*
meta: Логичный понедельник *new line*
category: Life *new line*
tags: Diary *new line*
publish: 02/02/2015 *new line*
author: poctek *new line*
headerPicture: diary.png *new line*
---